# How to get dead_greek on the F9 key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I'm trying to get my F9 key to function as the dead_greek compose character. It's not working.

I have a custom keyboard layout in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` called `mine`. It has this entry for the F9 key:

```
key <FK09> { [ dead_greek, dead_greek, dead_greek, dead_greek ] };
```

I have other characters in thsi file as well, so I know the file is being used. I can also run `xmodmap -pke | grep dead_greek` and get this output:

```
keycode  75 = dead_greek dead_greek dead_greek dead_greek dead_greek dead_greek XF86Switch_VT_9 dead_greek dead_greek XF86Switch_VT_9
```

The dead_greek key is there, but none of the Compose combinations work. If I type `dead_greek + a` for example I just `a`, not `α`.  This combination is listed in the `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` file, which I presume I'm using since other compose sequences from there work (but I'm positive as I don't know how to check which Compose file is in ue).

Why is my F9 not working as a dead_greek compose key?

---

For debugging I also ran `xev` and pressed F9. I get the output `state 0x10, keycode 75 (keysym 0xfe8c, dead_greek), same_screen YES,` indicating at least it is partially working, just not working as a greek compose key.

I'm using KDE in case that makes a difference. I also have multiple keyboard layouts, but the output from xmodmap shows dead_greek in all of the layouts.

Answer (score 4):

### `dead_greek` does not use the compose key

`/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` does not just dictate compose key combinations. When it does, they start with `<Multi_key>`, for example,

```
<Multi_key> <period> <period>       : "…"   ellipsis # HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
```

The entry for α is:

```
<dead_greek> <a>            : "α"   U03B1    # GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
```

Therefore, you should NOT press <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>dead_greek</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. You should instead press <kbd>dead_greek</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

As far as I can tell, your keymap is actually correct.

---

It's also worth noting that it didn't work in every application I tried (I was unable to use <kbd>dead_greek</kbd> in Sublime Text, but it worked in Google Chrome).

Comment: I'm trying just with F9+a, not the combination Compose+F9+a. It's like it just doesn't recognize the F9 at all.

Comment: Oops, my mistake!

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y In how many applications have you tried to use it? Mapping F9 to dead_greek worked for me.

Comment: Hmm, just tried it in Firefox again and it works here.  I thought I used it everywhere, but apparently none of my standard apps recognize it: Konsole, Kate, KDE menu... hmm, I wonder if it's all Qt apps?

Comment: It is strange since I have several other keymap modifications that work in the Konsole/Kate apps.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I tried it in Kdenlive (a QT app) and it worked (?).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69753/discussion-between-nonny-moose-and-eda-qa-mort-ora-y).